# firing click event for multiple div when holding the shift button

Tags: javascript, jquery

The goal that I want to achieve is when a user clicks on a specific div hold the shift button and then click on another div all the click event of the divs in between should be fired but I am stuck: http://jsfiddle.net/9q2e6/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#1").click(function (e) { 
        $(window).keydown(function (e) {
            var shiftKey = e.which == 16 || e.keyCode == 16 || e.charCode == 16;
            if (shiftKey) {

            }
        });
    });
 });
```

Comment: And you'd somehow like that work across both tables, or individually for each table ?

Comment: both tables i know what should i do but can't find a solution to put what i am thinking of and transform it into a code hahah i know that i should in some kind save the first clicked div and the second clicked div and loop through all there siblings and raise the click event

Comment: But there are no siblings, that's the problem, each DIV is within a TD, and there are two different tables ?

Comment: Here's a start at least -> http://jsfiddle.net/9q2e6/2/

Comment: yeah but as u can see each td that hold the table have an id and the id is incremented by 1

Comment: what PrevUntil function do ?

Comment: It does what it sounds like it does, it selects all previous elements until a certain element is encountered.

Comment: [How's this](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/9q2e6/7/)

Comment: yes Pete that's exactly what i am looking for but still there is a minor error in the keyup function i'll try to fix it can u please post your code  as an answer to accept it

Comment: Using the ID sound unreliable to me, but here goes anyway -> **http://jsfiddle.net/9q2e6/11/**